# how can a chemist detect the element boron in a sample of ordinary dust?

Tags: organic-chemistry

After the world trade center attack 22 years ago, the USGS sampled dust from the world trade center site and from lower Manhattan. They tested for every solid element except boron. I'm curious about this. I was told by a chemist that her electron microscope method (micro beam) was not a good way to search for boron. I'm trying to determine  what might be the best to go about this.

Comment: Mmm... probably some IR spectroscopy, depending on sample... But what's the point?

Comment: Perhaps boron was not considered a hazard? And I question if they checked for all solid elements -- can you provide a reference for that statement? Why *would* one test for iron, sodium, calcium or aluminum, common in dust from many sources?

Comment: I am trying to reconstruct why the USGS did what they did. I still don't know. That's why I posted here. Why boron? Good question. That cuts to the quick about the WTC collapse.

Comment: The USGS scientist I spoke with is a micro beam expert. She told me this method is not optional for identifying boron.

Comment: I don't think this is a bad question despite the down votes. However, the claim is indeed a bit fuzzy and could be substantiated with sources. For example where the claim is from what they tested about. For what it's worth, I don't even know what USGS stands for.

Comment: I have the US Geological Survey (USGS) dust study on order. When I have the data in hand I will answer your question.

Comment: I just hope eventual missing of boron analysis would not feed conspiration theorists.

Comment: you can find a reference for testing borons here <a href="https://books.google.it/books?id=wFSKximiFJAC&newbks=0&dq=determination%20of%20BOron%20in%20Air&hl=it&pg=PA162&source=bookclip&ci=85%2C134%2C845%2C1104"><img src="https://books.google.it/books/content?id=wFSKximiFJAC&hl=it&pg=PA162&img=1&zoom=3&bul=1&sig=ACfU3U2xR2q1mK146dKFc8OL5Pw-o4qE5Q&ci=85%2C134%2C845%2C1104&edge=0"/></a>

Comment: If you search on the web there are several papers on detecting Boron by flame Atomic Absorption Spectroscopy

Comment: As a light element, e-beam induced X-rays are indeed not a great technique. Mass spec, atomic emission, etc. are better.